# What is wrong with this Isabelle proof?

Tags: isabelle

This pattern generator produces a list with a given number at a given position, all other values are zero.

```
fun pattern_one_value :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list" where
"pattern_one_value _   _    _   0   = []" |
"pattern_one_value pos pos1 val lng = 
    (if pos = pos1 then val else 0) # (pattern_one_value pos (pos1 + 1) val (lng - 1))"
```

The following lemma is aimed to prove that generated lists contain the right value at the given position.

```
lemma pattern_one_value_check [simp]: "∀pos val. pos < lng ⟹ pattern_one_value pos 0 val lng ! pos = val"
    proof(induct lng)
        case 0         then show ?case by simp
    next
        case (Suc lng) then show ?case by auto
    qed
```

It seems to be a correct proof; however, changing `val` in the cons expression of the generator function into an arbitrary number like `(if pos = pos1 then 7 else 0) # ...`, the proof still holds because both the base and the induction hypothesis are false.
Where am I wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to be a correct proof; however, changing val in the cons
>   expression of the generator function into an arbitrary number like `(if pos = pos1 then 7 else 0) # ...`, the proof still holds because both
>   the base and the induction hypothesis are false. Where am I wrong?

I believe that the problem is related to an attempt to treat HOL's universal quantifier `∀` as equivalent to Pure's universal quantifier `⋀`. Effectively, it is possible to prove anything from the premise of the theorem `pattern_one_value_check`, as stated in your question. Indeed:

```
lemma pattern_one_value_check'[simp]:
  "(∀pos val::nat. pos < (lng::nat)) = False"
  by auto

lemma pattern_one_value_check''[simp]: 
  "(∀pos val::nat. pos < (lng::nat)) ⟹ P"
  by auto
```

I believe that you meant to use `Pure`'s universal quantification in the statement of the theorem, e.g.

```
lemma pattern_one_value_check [simp]: 
  "⋀pos val. pos < lng ⟹ pattern_one_value pos 0 val lng ! pos = val"
proof(induct lng)
  case 0 then show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc lng) then show ?case sorry
qed
```

In fact, even this is not necessary. The following theorem, once proven, will appear in the context as identical to the one stated above:

```
lemma pattern_one_value_check' [simp]: 
  "pos < lng ⟹ pattern_one_value pos 0 val lng ! pos = val"
proof(induct lng)
  case 0 then show ?case by simp
next
  case (Suc lng) then show ?case sorry
qed
```

---

If you seek a more detailed explanation, see Section 2.1 in Isar-ref and the document "Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL", both are part of the official documentation.

---

As a side note, I have to mention that, perhaps, there is an easier way to define `pattern_one_value`. In this case, the proof of `pattern_one_value_check` also seems to be easier:

```
definition pattern_one_value :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list"
  where "pattern_one_value val pos len = list_update (replicate len 0) pos val"

lemma pattern_one_value_check:
  assumes "pos < len" 
  shows "pattern_one_value val pos len ! pos = val"  
  using assms unfolding pattern_one_value_def
  apply(induct len)
  subgoal by auto
  subgoal by (metis length_replicate nth_list_update)
  done
```