# How to include statement about type of the variable in the Isabelle/HOL term

Tags: isabelle

I have following simple Isabelle/HOL theory:

```
theory Max_Of_Two_Integers_Real
  imports Main
    "HOL-Library.Multiset"
    "HOL-Library.Code_Target_Numeral"
    "HOL-Library.Code_Target_Nat"
    "HOL-Library.Code_Abstract_Nat"
begin

definition two_integer_max_case_def :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"two_integer_max_case_def a b = (case a > b of True ⇒ a | False ⇒ b)"

lemma spec_final:
  fixes a :: nat and b :: nat
  assumes "a > b" (* and "b < a" *)
  shows "two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  using assms by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def) 

lemma spec_1:
  fixes a :: nat and b :: nat
  shows "a > b ⟹ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def) 

lemma spec_2:
  shows " (a ∈ nat set) ∧ (b ∈ nat set) ∧  (a > b) ⟹ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)

end
```

Three lemmas try to express and prove that same statement, but progressively I am trying to move information from assumes and fixes towards the term. First 2 lemmas are correct, but the third (last) lemma is failing syntactically with the error message:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "int"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  nat :: int ⇒ nat
Operand:   set :: ??'a list ⇒ ??'a set
```

My aim in this lemma is to move type information from the fixes towards the term/statement? How I make statements about the type of variable in the term (of inner syntax)?

Maybe I should use, if I am trying to avoid fixes clause (in which the variables may be declared), the full ForAll expression like:

```
lemma spec_final_3:
  shows "∀ a :: nat . ∀ b :: nat . ( (a > b) ⟹ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a)"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)
```

But it is failing syntactically as well with the error message:

```
Inner syntax error: unexpected end of input⌂
Failed to parse prop
```

So - is it possible to include type statements in the term directly (without fixes clause) and is there any difference between fixes clause and type statement in the term? Maybe such differences start to appear during (semi)automatic proofs, e.g., when simplification tactics are applied or some other tactics?

Comment: Look at https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/prog-prove.pdf, Sect 3.1 (including the figure): you cannot use ⟹ in ∀. And you don't need to quantify you terms (you are really fighting the system if you do so), just replace the first occurrence of `a` by `(a::nat)`.

Comment: This reminds me of a question that I answered some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782066/what-is-wrong-with-this-isabelle-proof/: it seems like it can be easy to fall into the trap of confusing the syntax of the meta-logic Isabelle/Pure and the syntax of the object logic Isabelle/HOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nat set` is interpreted as a function (that does not type correctly). The set of natural numbers can be expressed as `UNIV :: nat set`. Then, `spec_2` reads

```
lemma spec_2:
  shows "a ∈ (UNIV :: nat set) ∧ b ∈ (UNIV :: nat set) ∧ a > b ⟹
         two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)
```

However, more natural way would be to include the type information in `spec_1` without `fixes` clause:

```
lemma spec_1':
  shows "(a :: nat) > (b :: nat) ⟹ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)
```

`∀` belongs to HOL, so the HOL implication should be used in `spec_final_3`:

```
lemma spec_final_3:
  shows "∀ a :: nat. ∀ b :: nat. a > b ⟶ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)
```

`spec_1` can also be rewritten using an explicit meta-logic qualification (and implication) to look similar to `spec_final_3`:

```
lemma spec_1'':
  shows "⋀ a :: nat. ⋀ b :: nat. a > b ⟹ two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
  by (simp add: two_integer_max_case_def_def)
```